# mongodb error- db.runCommand() is not a function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I want to modify the validation of my collection using collmod command. but when I call the runCommand() function it gives me error runCommand is not a function. I am trying to connect using nodejs driver

```
const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
client.db('E-commerce').runCommand({collmod:'category',categorySchema})
```

Comment: Try `client.getSiblingDB('E-commerce').runCommand`

Comment: I have tried using getSiblingDB but it shows getSiblingDb is not a function

Comment: `getSiblingDB` or `getSiblingDb`? Perhaps `client.db.getSiblingDB('E-commerce').runCommand`

Comment: nope it is also not working. Same error. I have created using createCollection instead of using collmod. I thing this works for only mongosh